# PostgreSQL delete duplicate rows ignoring case

Tags: postgresql, case-insensitive, duplicates

I need to delete from a table rows that have the same value on a specified field ignoring case. For example if I have a row that has 'foo' as value for a field and another row that has 'Foo' as value for the same field, I want to delete only one of these rows (keeping 1 row).
I've tried something like this:

```
delete from table t1 
where exists (select 1 
              from table t2 
              where t1.key <> t2.key 
                and t1.field ILIKE t2.field)
```

but this deletes the other row too.
Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `<>` by `<`:

```
DELETE
  FROM table t1 
 WHERE exists (
    SELECT 1 
      FROM table t2 
     WHERE t1.key < t2.key 
       and t1.field ILIKE t2.field
 )
```

This way you keep the rows with the highest `key`. You also could use `>` to keep the records with the lowest `key`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `key` is the primary key of the table:

```
DELETE FROM the_table t1
WHERE t1.key not in (select min(t2.key)
                     from the_table t2
                     group by lower(t2.field));
```